# How to connect form a Guest MacOs to Host Windows localhost

Tags: asp.net, operating-system, virtual-machine, virtualbox, vmware

My OS is Windows 10. I'm using VmWare to run MacOs as a virtual machine. On my host I have web development server running on localhost:44399. I have Nat connection in the settings. I've tried a lot of ways to establish the connection but nothing helped. Already modified the hosts file and so on but I can't access localhost:44399 from MacOs guest. Can anyone help me? Here are the app settings
[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `localhost`, you need put your host IP address. `localhost` on your guest pointing to your guest no host machine.

Comment: Are you ably to ping your host from guest by IP address?